# Flutter not returning anything

Tags: flutter, dart

I changed nothing major but all of a sudden my flutter app has stopped loading. It returns no errors when debugging, but simply loads nothing. I was previously getting an error because I was calling a class within a class so I removed it Any help would be appreciated.

```
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names, avoid_print, unused_import
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() async {
// ...
// Needs to be called so that we can await for EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
// ...
runApp(const FirstRoute());
}

class FirstRoute extends StatefulWidget {
const FirstRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
@override
State<FirstRoute> createState() => _FirstRouteState();
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return BlocProvider(
  create: (context) => LanguageCubit(),
  child: BlocBuilder<LanguageCubit, Locale>(builder: (context, lang) {
    return MaterialApp(
        locale: lang,
        title: 'Localizations Sample App',
        localizationsDelegates: const [
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: const [
          Locale('en', ''), // English, no country code
          Locale('de', ''), // Spanish, no country code
          Locale('pt', ''),
        ],
        home: const FirstRoute());
  }),
);
}
}

class _FirstRouteState extends State<FirstRoute> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return const MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: [
    AppLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    Locale('en', ''),
    Locale('de', ''),
    Locale('pt', ''),
  ],
);
}
}
```

Comment: What did you remove?

Comment: did you added any library or updated any library/dependency in between??

Comment: Why is your build() method inside a `StatefulWidget`? It isn't used since `StatefulWidget` doesn't include `build` method in itself. It uses its `State`'s build method which - in your case - has no `home` parameter specified so no screen can apeear. Try to cut out your `build` method from `FirstRoute` widget and place it inside `_FirstRouteState` (replace the `build` method that is there already).

Comment: @FirentisTFW That results in the following error, which is what I was initially trying to remove from my program: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this: is not true'